# How to show Views, which are selected in a tab bar, upon each others?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a tabBar with 5 options, two of the options must be shown as a side menus(with clear background color), which means they have a previously selected view being seen as a background.

I have the only idea of making it with a ZStack which consists of three views and changing the opacity of the last two.

```
VStack {
   if selectedTab == .firstOpaque {
      ZStack {
         firstOpaqueView()
         firstClearView().opacity(firstViewOpacity)
         secondClearView().opacity(secondViewOpacity)
      }
   } else if selectedTab == .secondOpaque {
      ZStack {
         secondOpaqueView()
         firstClearView().opacity(firstViewOpacity)
         secondClearView().opacity(secondViewOpacity)
      }
   } else if selectedTab == .thirdOpaque {
      ZStack {
         thirdOpaqueView()
         firstClearView().opacity(firstViewOpacity)
         secondClearView().opacity(secondViewOpacity)
      }
   }

   CustomTabBarView()
}
```

But this seems inefficient. Is there any other way or this one is the only?

Comment: Might change that to a `switch selectedTab { case .firstOpaque...}` Also, are you referring to a view carousel?

Comment: @xTwisteDx No, not carousel. Selected tab lays upon previous one as a sided menu, with a clear background.